# PHP compilation process stops with errors when configure option '--with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC' is set

Tags: php, pdo, compiler-errors, odbc

I tried to compile PHP 5.5.31 sources on Ubuntu 14.04. with PDO ODBC enabled. Configure command runs smoothly without errors, but when I start compiling, I got the following errors:

```
/bin/bash /vagrant/php-5.5.31/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile cc -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext  -I/usr/local/include -DPDO_ODBC_TYPE=\"unixODBC\" -Iext/pdo_odbc/ -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/include -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/main -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31 -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/date/lib -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/ereg/regex -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/ads/php/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/c-client -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/usr/include/mysql -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/TSRM -I/vagrant/php-5.5.31/Zend    -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -c /vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c -o ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.lo
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c: In function ‘odbc_handle_closer’:
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:131:16: error: ‘SQL_NULL_HANDLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:131:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c: In function ‘odbc_handle_preparer’:
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:186:32: error: ‘SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_SCROLLABLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:186:67: error: ‘SQL_SCROLLABLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c: In function ‘odbc_handle_doer’:
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:238:12: error: ‘SQL_NO_DATA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c: In function ‘odbc_handle_begin’:
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:278:87: error: ‘SQL_IS_INTEGER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c: In function ‘odbc_handle_commit’:
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:304:86: error: ‘SQL_IS_INTEGER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c: In function ‘odbc_handle_rollback’:
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:329:86: error: ‘SQL_IS_INTEGER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c: In function ‘pdo_odbc_handle_factory’:
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:402:33: error: ‘SQL_NULL_HANDLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:403:29: error: ‘SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:403:59: error: ‘SQL_OV_ODBC3’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/vagrant/php-5.5.31/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:427:76: error: ‘SQL_IS_INTEGER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.lo] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it didn't find unixODBC include files. Be sure to install `unixodbc-dev`